# Use XA Datasource in JPA Queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jta, xa

I need a jta implementation in myservices.For that reason I use XADatasource in my entityManagerFactory in spring boot.
But MyScenario like this my api project has 12 services.

I have 10 services for select services,and other 2 services need distributed transaction

Is there any overhead to use XA Datasoure in Selective JPA Queries

Is there any comparison for running jpa queries between XA DAtasource and Hikari Datasource